# jQuery search for individual words not string of words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Question:

I have a jQuery search function however it searches for words together not individually. e.g. "ASUS B350" not "ASUS" and "B350" this can be seen when searching for Asus STRIX B350-F GAMING, "ASUS B350" produces no result but "ASUS" and "B350" would.

## Code:

```
$("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr:not(.discarded) td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

## Expected Result:

I also want if the string is encased in "" it searches for those words in order.

If you need any more details please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to `filter` based on whether *any* of the words are included?

Comment: #mySearch is a search bar and i want to search for all words but if they are all in column but in any order unless they are encapsulated with ""

Comment: You need to split up the words in the search term, search for each one individually for each row, and if any of the words are not found in a given row, discard that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the words at every space and check if those individual words exist in the text using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

Now if you search for "Asus strix" in the below snippet, both ASUS results will be shown

```js
$("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr:not(.discarded) td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
        let toggle = value.split(" ").every(i => !i || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(i) > -1);
        $(this).parent().toggle(toggle);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mySearch" />
<table id="myTable">
 <tr><td>Asus STRIX B350-F GAMING</td></tr> 
 <tr><td>Asus ROG Strix SCAR II Gaming</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dell G7 15 Gaming Laptop</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, is it hard to add a check for "" around entire string and skip splitting the value?

Comment: Searching for "`asus s`" results in both `Asus STRIX B350-F GAMING` and `ASUS Gaming` being shown. Edit: this was before your latest change in which the following items were included: `Asus STRIX B350-F GAMING` and `ASUS Gaming` - with the latter not having "strix" included.

Comment: @Chri.s yes. OP hasn't mentioned whether we could repeat matched texts. If that is required, we should use regular expression.

Comment: @Uskompuf that would make the question as "Too broad" I think. You can check the other answer posted here. But, make sure to validate for odd number of `"` in your text

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp pattern to find out if individual words are occurring in the string:

```
$("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  if(!(value.startsWith('"')&&value.endsWith('"'))){
        value=value.replace(" ", "|");
        value= value.trim();
  }else {
    value=value.replace("\"", "");
  }
  $("#myTable tr:not(.discarded) td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().match(value));
  });
});
```